# Rationalization of $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}}$ (symmetric formula with multi-index)

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, radicals, irrational-numbers, set-partition

### Motivation

No particular motivation, I'm just curious to see if an interesting result can emerge from such a seemingly simple problem.

### Problem

Find the closed symmetric formula for the rationalization of
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\right)^{-1}$$

**Initial formulas**

With $n=1$ is trivial:
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{a}=\frac{a^{\frac{3}{2}}}{a^2}$$
With $n=2$ we have
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{a-b}$$
Doing the average with the version with $a$ and $b$ exchanged we have:
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}=\frac{a^{\frac{3}{2}}+b^{\frac{3}{2}}-a\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}b}{a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}}$$
With $n=3$ the interesting part begins: rationalizing with the usual conjugate rule you can obtain $3$ different forms (all equivalent to each other):
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\begin{cases}
\frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})}{(a+b-c)^2-4ab}\\
\frac{(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a})(b+c-a-2\sqrt{bc})}{(b+c-a)^{2}-4bc}\\
\frac{(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(c+a-b-2\sqrt{ca})}{(c+a-b)^{2}-4ca}\end{cases}$$
However, these $3$ formulas are not symmetrical, so I averaged them, and I got:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{a^{\frac{3}{2}}+b^{\frac{3}{2}}+c^{\frac{3}{2}}-a\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}b-a\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}c-\sqrt{b}c-b\sqrt{c}+2\sqrt{abc}}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-2ab-2bc-2ca}$$
For a generic $n$ there will be $n$ different shapes with the "cycled" elements, in the end the symmetric result will be their average.

---

I would be curious to see if there is a closed formula for generic $n$, I hypothesize that the final formula could be something like:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i_1+...+i_n=3}\mathcal{C}_{i_1,...,i_n}\sqrt{a_1^{i_1} a_2^{i_2}\cdot...\cdot a_n^{i_n}}}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2-2\sum_{1\geq i>j\geq n}a_i a_j}$$
it can be written similarly
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_i}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{|\mathbf{i}|=3}\mathcal{C}_{\mathbf{i}}\sqrt{\mathbf{a}^{\mathbf{i}}}}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2-2\sum_{1\geq i>j\geq n}a_i a_j}$$
Where $\mathcal{C}_{i_1,...,i_n}$ is a constant that depends on the partition of $n$. In the second formula I used multi-index notation where $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $\mathbf{i}=(i_1,...,i_n)$

---

### Generalization

An immediate generalization then would also be to try to find the formula of
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt[m]{a_i}\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: I don't think you can do it with just quadratic in the denominator, which should be of degree $2^{n-1}$.  You only have one free choice about which $a_i$ to consider the $+\sqrt{a_i}$ instead of the other $\pm\sqrt{a_j}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yup, but by developing the calculations a lot of terms are eliminated and only the terms with a degree less than or equal to 2 remain. For $n=3$ it was coming $(a^2 - 2 a b - 2 a c + b^2 - 2 b c + c^2)^3$ at denominator, but it was simplified with the numerator then.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess don't actually understand your "average" procedure then.  For $n=2$ the "average" should have given you $\frac{0}{0}$ because numerator and denominator are both antisymmetric in $a,b$ and $\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{a-b}=\frac{\sum_{sym}(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})}{\sum_{sym}(a-b)}=\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: @user10354138 For $n=2$ you do this: $a\mapsto b, b\mapsto a$ then you average:
$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{a-b}+\frac{\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}}{b-a}\right)=\frac{a^{\frac{3}{2}}+b^{\frac{3}{2}}-a\sqrt{b}-b\sqrt{a}}{a^{2}+b^{2}-2ab}$.
For $n=3$ you do $a\mapsto b, b\mapsto c, c\mapsto a$